# How to use the current phone theme colors and images in QML for Symbian?

Tags: qt, qml, symbian, qt-quick

I’m developing a Symbian app in QML, my root element is `PageStackWindow`.

I want it to get the current theme’s “app background image”, instead of the default Nokia theme one.

Also, when I press on a `ListItem`, I want it to take the current theme “on list item pressed” image.

I have searched a lot but couldn’t figure out how to do this.. but I’m guessing that `platformStyle` and `privateStyle` are related to this somehow, unfortunately I didn’t find any docs about them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are working with the QtQuick Components with the SYmbian theme. `platformStyle` and `privateStyle` are both defined internally by the components pack to replicate the Symbian theme, not by the Symbian OS itself. You most likely need to find some sort of system call you can make in C++ to get the background image.  The components have no ties or calls into the OS itself.  This is so they can be used on any platform.

Comment: I see. I managed to find the functions of `platformStyle` and `privateStyle` in the [QtQuick Components for Symbian source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/qt-components/source/e60e99e0fc378a7fd74d7cea90d81dac9dc5e578:src/symbian).
Do you know where I can find info on how to find the current theme of the OS?